# Git Log - get all commit that have been merged onto a branch after a given date

Tags: git, tortoisegit

I have an application that is being audited. Every month, I am asked to present the list of commits that have been deployed to production.

I have 3 main branches : master; UAT and PROD.
Devs are made in the master or specific branches, UAT has the code that is in the QA server, and PROD has the code that is deployed in production.

Sometimes it happens that the User Acceptance Test phase takes longer than one month (last deploy in production had commits that were developped six months ago) and here is where my problems start.

With the command `git log --pretty=format:"%h";"%an";"%ai";"%cn";"%ci";"%s" PROD --since='2022-01-01'` I can get the list of commits that have been commited since January first, however, I cannot get the commits that have been merged into PROD branch but have been commited before that date.

Is there a simple query to get the full list of commits merged into PROD branch since January 1st, regardless of their commit date?

Comment: Git does not keep that information. It keeps commit dates, but not merge dates. I would recommend keeping a record of where PROD was last time you created the report, and listing commits that are on PROD now that were not on PROD then. Since you have to do this report monthly, it should not be hard to keep the sha1 of PROD when do create the report, to be available next time.

Comment: To be clear, what I mean is that among the history of a commit, Git has no way to know which commit any given branch was actually pointing to at a given past date. It is possible your Git server keeps a history of pushes, and maybe you could consult that, or maybe the list of PRs. But that's not a Git thing, it would be a thing provided by the server implementation you're using.

Comment: When are merges done into PROD? Is it approximately when the code is deployed to Prod? If yes, are the merges fast forward or is there a merge commit? If there is a merge commit, then does `git log --first-parent PROD` show you all deployments to Prod at about the proper time they occurred? If yes, then you can use the first parent list for the compares. (If your merges are oftentimes fast-forward this won't work, but the fact that you want this might build a case for using `--no-ff` for future merges into your long-lived branches.)

Answer (score 0):

##### TL;DR

No, Git cannot do this for you. But there are work-arounds.

##### Details

Git itself does not keep track of the information you're looking for. It has no way to knowing, among the history of a branch, which commit it was actually pointing to at any given past date.

##### A possible work-around

If you knew where PROD was before you start date, say at OLDPROD, you could use

```
git log OLDPROD..PROD
```

So here are my suggestions for ways to have OLDPROD available:

- Since you're running this report monthly, save which commit PROD was at when you last ran the report, so it's available to your next time you run the report.
- If you have a consistent and regular workflow, e.g., every merge into PROD has to be done via a PR merging into PROD, you could inspect the logs and find the most recent merge before your start date: that would be OLDPROD.
- Depending on what Git server you use, it might keep logs of push operations: the last push to PROD before your start date would be OLDPROD.
- If you're consistently using PRs, the history of PRs on your Git server should also provide enough information to infer OLDPROD.